# How can I assign the key Super+M» to minimize all windows in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys, keyboard, shortcuts

Everytime I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> the Dash lens for music appears.

I have tried changing this behaviour using **System Tools** ▸ **Keyboard** ▸ **Shortcuts** ▸ **Navigation** ▸ **Hide all windows** to assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> but it does not work.

I have also tried using CompizSetting to change the Unity shortcuts, but it seems that the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut is not defined here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

A quick workaround would be to remove the **Unity Music Lens**.

Open a terminal (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-music
```

You will be asked for your password. Type it in and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then log out and log in again.

Now you can assing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to **minimize all windows** through **System Tools** ▸ **Keyboard** ▸ **Shortcuts** ▸ **Navigation** ▸ **Hide all windows**

Comment: Really smart idea! I have tested this and it works!

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the *.lens files to change the hotkey or disable the lenses.
More http://ubuntu-answers.blogspot.com/2012/05/change-dash-lens-hotkey.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I already solved this problem using the workaround from @GevorgHindoyan. I still wonder if this could be done using some kind of GUI dialog...

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is:

Use the shortcut: <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

<kbd>Super</kbd> is the same key with Windows logo generally or the function key for the laptops.

Hope this helps.